# git command on vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, command

I try to write on vscode terminal git init and take this error :

> The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spellin
> g of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

on my cmd when it works .
i install git
and put path in environment variables correctly
and I checked from settings of vscode enabled git.
so what should i do to work the command git on vscode terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) type:
*Create New Integrated Terminal*
Now you have to change the terminal (Powershell -> Git Bash)
by clicking on the tab (the down arrow) in the upper right corner of the Integrated Terminal Window:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are working on Windows.

If you work in Windows, the terminal executed in vscode is not the same as the terminal provided by git, what would explain the described behavior.

The vscode terminal executes the power shell terminal, meanwhile the terminal provided by git executes a bash-like terminal (the most common terminal used in linux) with all commonly used tools.

Under 'vscode > settings > Features > Terminal' you can change this behavior